# Как вывести русский текст, записанный с неправильной кодировкой?

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка

У меня есть PDF файл, содержащий русский текст. Файл был сгенерирован не совсем правильно, и в нем отсутствует информация о том, какая кодировка используется. Сам файл отображается нормально, но когда копирую из него текст, то получается только набор латинских букв с акцентами. К примеру слово «манускрипт» копируется как «ìàíóñêðèïò».

Попробовал следующие команды, но не получилось получить изначальное слово:

```
~$ echo "ìàíóñêðèïò" | iconv -f CP1251 -t utf-8 -
Г¬Г Г­ГіГ±ГЄГ°ГЁГЇГІ
~$ echo "ìàíóñêðèïò" | iconv -f ISO-8859-5 -t utf-8 -
УЌУ У­УГУБУЊУАУЈУЏУВ
~$ echo "ìàíóñêðèïò" | iconv -f KOI8-R -t utf-8 -
ц╛ц═ц╜цЁц╠ц╙ц╟ц╗ц╞ц╡
~$ echo "ìàíóñêðèïò" | iconv -f CP866 -t utf-8 -
├м├а├н├│├▒├к├░├и├п├▓
```

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: `echo "ìàíóñêðèïò" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t LATIN1 | iconv -f CP1251 -t UTF-8` // манускрипт

Comment: @AlexeyTen: Принцип, я думаю, понял. Спасибо. Напишите ваш комментарий в виде ответа, я вам галочку поставлю.